# Distributive property involving Cartesian products in sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am going through Hammack's *Book of Proof* and encountered a problem in the "Intersection, Union" subchapter. The reader is asked to justify whether they think the expression $$(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{N}=(\mathbb{R \times \mathbb{N}}) - (\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N})$$ is true, or false?

The proof is the following...
$$\begin{align*}
(x,y)\in (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{N}&\iff x\in(\mathbb{R} -\mathbb{Z})\wedge y\in \mathbb{N} \\ 
&\iff x\in\mathbb{R}  \wedge  x\notin \mathbb{Z} \wedge  y\in\mathbb{N} \\ 
&\iff (x,y)\in (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N})\wedge (x,y)\notin (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N})  \\
&\iff  (x,y) \in (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}) - (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N})   
\end{align*} $$

My question is whether there is a general distributive property for Cartesian products and sets that I am unaware of. I thought about it when I saw that the expression was true, but I am unsure. If it indeed exists, it would be very useful to have such property on hand for future problems...

Comment: Maybe you mean distributive property? The proof for these particular three sets should work for any three sets.

Comment: "communicative" is something to do with communication. "Commutative" is something to co with commutation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin; @GregMartin, also pointed out my mistake in phrasing...Could you instead edit my post into "Distributive property involving Cartesian products in sets" and change the word commutative with distributive? Thank you

Comment: @Aristarchus_ You can edit your post yourself!